# household_objects database

Tags: ros, household-objects-database

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all,

I followed those steps(http://www.ros.org/wiki/sql_database/Tutorials/Installing%20a%20PostgreSQL%20Server) to link the database, but it failed. The errors are as below. The version of Ubuntu is 11.04. Thanks.

```
/usr/bin/pg_restore --host 10.217.132.113 --port 5432 --username willow --dbname \"household_objects-0.2\" --verbose "/home/kptee/database/household_objects-0.2.backup"
pg_restore: connecting to database for restore
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] connection to database ""household_objects-0.2"" failed: FATAL:  database ""household_objects-0.2"" does not exist
pg_restore: *** aborted because of error

Process returned exit code 1.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10790/household_objects-database/) by [Nutan](https://answers.ros.org/users/170/nutan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2011-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nutan,

I have never used pg_restore from the command line, so can offer no advice there. I always use the pgadmin GUI, it works great for me, you can get it via sudo apt-get install pgadmin3

---

Originally posted by [Matei Ciocarlie](https://answers.ros.org/users/36/matei-ciocarlie/) with karma: 586 on 2011-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-01-09**:
thanks Nutan it worked when i removed the . in the name of the database :)

**Comment by [Nutan](https://answers.ros.org/users/170/nutan/) on 2011-08-03**:
if figured it out. In pgadmin, i use the name of "household_objects-0.2", but it could not contain the point.